# fstream get(char*, int) how to operate empty line?

Tags: c++, get, fstream

code in strfile.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#define SZ 100

using namespace std;

int main(){
char buf[SZ];
{
    ifstream in("strfile.cpp");
    assert(in);
    ofstream out("strfile.out");
    assert(out);
    int i = 1;

    while(!in.eof()){
        if(in.get(buf, SZ))
            int a = in.get();
        else{
            cout << buf << endl;
            out << i++ << ": " << buf << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout << buf << endl;
        out << i++ << ": " << buf << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I want to operate all file
but in strfile.out:

```
1: #include <fstream>
2: #include <iostream>
3: #include <assert.h>
4: ...(many empty line)
```

I know that fstream.getline(char*, int) this function can manage it,but I want to know how to do this just use the function "fstream.get()".

Comment: What do you mean "how to operate"? Do you want to ignore empty lines? Is your code failing on empty lines?

Comment: sorry for my poor english..what i what is that when there is a empty    line, output it with line number.

Comment: If you want to copy a file and insert a line number at each line or after 100 characters, whichever happens first, it works fine for me. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: @lanmezhe: Do you want to output line numbers only on empty lines?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have know how to do, thank you all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ifstream::get(char*,streamsize)` will leave the delimiter (in this case `\n`) on the stream, your call never advances and thus it appears to your calling program that you are endlessly reading blank lines.

Instead you need to determine if a newline is waiting on the stream, and move past it using `in.get()` or `in.ignore(1)`:

```
ifstream in("strfile.cpp");
ofstream out("strfile.out");

int i = 1;
out << i << ": ";

while (in.good()) {
    if (in.peek() == '\n') {
        // in.get(buf, SZ) won't read newlines
        in.get();
        out << endl << i++ << ": ";
    } else {
        in.get(buf, SZ);
        out << buf;      // we only output the buffer contents, no newline
    }
}

// output the hanging \n
out << endl;

in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: thanks,I know getline() can do it. I just want to know how to do this only use get().

Comment: thank you, it works! I think the problem is that when the get(buf,SZ) read the empty line, the program went wrong. Is that right?

Comment: What happens is it leaves the `\n` on the stream, repeated calls to `get(buf, SZ)` stop at the newline and thus you never progress. It actually just hasn't moved *past* the end of the line.