# C++ fstream keep reading the same first 5 lines?

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop, ifstream, file-pointer

I'm really frustrated. I'm trying to read a txt file which has the following content:

```
Arenas
Edward
239924731
2525976612

Autry
Richard
527646269
6028236739
```

Using this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
     string line;
     string last, first;
     int uin, number;
     ifstream phoneBook;
     phoneBook.open("PhoneBook.txt");

    while (!phoneBook.eof()) {
        phoneBook >> last >> first >> uin >> number;
        cout << last << ", " << first << ", " << uin << ", " << number <<endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```

The output would be the same contact endlessly

```
Arenas, Edward, 239924731, 2147483647
Arenas, Edward, 239924731, 2147483647
Arenas, Edward, 239924731, 2147483647
Arenas, Edward, 239924731, 2147483647
Arenas, Edward, 239924731, 2147483647
```

I also tried this version of while loop:

```
while (phoneBook >> last >> first >> uin >> number) {

    cout << last << ", " << first << ", " << uin << ", " << number <<endl;
}
```

For some reasons, the compiler doesn't even step into the loop. It would just jump to return 0;

Comment: Also, it's generally a good idea to store phone numbers as text rather than integers. What if it began with a 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `number` values are too big to fit into a four-byte signed integer.  Maximum value for that is 2147483647 (2^31 - 1), which is why you get that printing out at the end.  (You weren't asking about *that* issue; I don't know how I noticed it myself!)

But what I'm also wondering about is that extra line that you have in between each record.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453522/fstream-getchar-int-how-to-operate-empty-line) that discusses `fstream`s and delimiters.  I wonder if it's getting stuck at the blank line, reading nothing, and then just outputting the same values of `last`, `first`, `uin`, and `number`.

Comment: Obviously, it does print it out fine for the first contact. The problem is the while loop. It is not functioning as expected!

Comment: I edited my answer as you were commenting.  (Also you might want to use `long int` for your `number` variable.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a different type of error.  The best method to use is `ios::good`:

```
while (!phoneBook.good()) {
```

Comment: I tried this one, it did not work. It loops once only and print one contact.